# How to read the HTML Components class Text Value

Tags: jquery

I have got the following the HTML Component

```
<ul id="weekList" class="week-menu" role="menu" style="display: block;"> 
            <li><a data-value="SUN"><i class="hym sunday"></i>Sunday</a></li> 
            <li><a data-value="MON"><i class="hym monday"></i>Monday</a></li> 
             <li><a data-value="TUE"><i class="hym tuesday"></i>TUesday</a></li> 
</ul>
```

I am trying to read the Value **hym monday**  based on the input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let val = 'MON'
    var aaa = $("#weekList li").find("a[data-value='MON']")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(aaa))
});
```

I have tried as folllowing

https://jsfiddle.net/j1zcf0ed/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.text()` to `$("#weekList li").find("a[data-value='MON']")`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let val = 'MON'
  var aaa = $("#weekList li").find("a[data-value='MON'] i").attr("class")
  console.log(JSON.stringify(aaa))
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let val = 'MON'
  var aaa = $("#weekList li").find("a[data-value='MON'] i").attr("class")
  console.log(JSON.stringify(aaa))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="weekList" class="week-menu" role="menu" style="display: block;">
  <li><a data-value="SUN"><i class="hym sunday"></i>Sunday</a></li>
  <li><a data-value="MON"><i class="hym monday"></i>Monday</a></li>
  <li><a data-value="TUE"><i class="hym tuesday"></i>TUesday</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , but I need the Text hym monday , not Monday